# RESTful services : unable to call jsp page

Tags: java, rest

I am new to RESTful web services and i am trying to learn its annotations.

So far I was making a method and through typing unique URI I used to access the services.

But now i am trying to test @FormParam annotation. For that I have made one login form and also I have a service method to get user entered login name and password and print it.

Here is my code :

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="login">

Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
<br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**My service method.**

```
@Path("login")
    @POST
    public String login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password) {
        System.out.println("in login method");
        return "Logged with " +email + " " + password;
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But my problem is when I try to select my login.jsp and do Run As-->Run on server then it gives me

```
**HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /login.jsp of full path: http://localhost:8080/RestfulMoreAnnotations/login.jsp**
```

I am I missing out something?

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Should not the @Path("login") be @Path("/login")?

Comment: U may b right but my problem is my login form itself is not getting retrieved first to enter login details. My mistake that you pointed out will occur when I do submit after filling in login details.

Comment: Then you should implement GET for the login to process get requests from browser and return proper view (login.jsp in your case) or you can try to create just plain html rather than jsp

Comment: Ok..But how to return view? Can you please share some examples.?

Comment: e.g. http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/java/spring/mvc but you can google for SpringMVC tutorial

Comment: OHk..I thought there would be some mechanism in RESTful itself to return jsp page.

Comment: IMHO service returns something I would say some data or does something. It's not supposed to provide visible representation.